# Auto-Resize Radio Button when browser zoom

Tags: css, radio-button

I have a time selector built with two input type="radio" inside of a div. When browser zoom, the radioS don't auto-size and . How could I get this autosize using CSS?

Pics of the problem:

[image: Before browser zoom]
[image: After browser zoom]

My code is:

```html
<div id="timePeriodSelector" style="font-size: 100%">
<form action="">
<input type="radio" id="timePeriodSelector_default" onclick="Dash.dateTypeSwitcher('default')">Effective Date
<input type="radio" id="timePeriodSelector_secondary" onclick="Dash.dateTypeSwitcher('secondary')">Billing Date
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: As browser zoom you are talking about the Ctrl + Scroll function ? Why do you need it ?

Comment: Yes. The problem is with Crtl+ scroll function

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>   
    #timePeriodSelector{
        border: 1px dotted black;
    }   
  </style>

<body>
    <div id="timePeriodSelector" style="font-size: 100%">
        <form action="">
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriodSelector_default" onclick="Dash.dateTypeSwitcher('default')">Effective Date
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriodSelector_secondary" onclick="Dash.dateTypeSwitcher('secondary')">Billing Date
        </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>


It is work correctly in chrome
```